# Designing in QtCreator

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qt-designer

I am developing an application having a main form(ui) which has many groups, tabs, buttons, labels, etc.

While editing/designing a widget I have to reduce the size of all other widgets(groups, tabs, buttons, labels, etc.).

My problem is when all the widgets are at their desired size it creates a lot of confusion and can’t edit/design the required widget.

So my question is how can I hide all other widgets automatically while editing/designing a particular widget.

Comment: But there are scroll bars, not? Also, in general it is better if your GUI is resizable. I am often annoyed when application windows can't be resized properly. Of course there are exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

You can put each custom widget in a single UI file and let the parent widget include it. Just add a regular widget, right click on it and choose *Promote to...*. Then enter the class name and path to the header file.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. I followed your steps, but it creates different header files for each UI file. So I have to include every Ui header file and its class in parent's source file. Is there anyway to add the code of every UI file in a single header file?

Comment: @DennisBradley I don't think so, why do you want to merge different UI header files?

Comment: Different UI header files creates different class names and I have to manually implement those classes in my parent's source file(.cpp file). Can you please tell me what promoted class name and header file I should add while selecting the "Promoted widgets" option?

Comment: @DennisBradley The class name of your custom widget you want to add and the name/path of your own header file where it is defined. Those two are generated automatically if you choose to add a *Qt Designer Form Class* via QtCreator's GUI.

Comment: I am using Qt Designer Form, so for it what class name and header file path I should add?